# PictureBox Dispose() causing the PictureBox to become invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know when I put `pictureBox1.Dispose()`, the `PictureBox` becomes invisible.

Is there any way which  I could allow the `PictureBox` to remain with it being `Disposed`?

The reasons I `Dispose` is because I am using fingerprint in two separate forms.

Therefore, I have to `Dispose()` the fingerprint in the first form to take in second form.

Is it possible not disposing it while allow taking fingerprint in second form?

Comment: What do you mean by "fingerprint"? That's not a standard feature of winforms, so if you're using some library or somesuch, you need to explain which one and how you're using it. We can't read your mind.

Comment: sir, i am using flexcode sdk... can i know like is it possible to dispoe and then allow back to normal the fignerprint image

Comment: No, as I have already told you you cannot dispose an object you intend to keep using. Does whatever library you're using really tie into a `PictureBox` instance somehow? What happens if you just don't dispose it?

Comment: if i did not diipsose if give error whereby it states protected memory

Comment: I think at this point you would be better off deleting this question and asking a new one where you **paste your code**  (at least the relevant part)and also mention that you are using "Flexcode SDK" in the question so that people who know about that library see it.

Comment: thanks sir i will do i now.

Comment: You can dispose of the Bitmap shown in it: Store a reference, Set it to null, dispose of the reference!

Comment: thanks is there any sample for me to follow

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Don't dispose it if you still need it. Disposing it while you still use it will result in undefined behavior and doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: thanks, the problem is, i have to take fingerprint in different forms, two forms in the same visual studio, so it is not necessry to dispose the image inorder to takein another form the fingerpritn?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about fingerprints. Maybe you should include more information in your question? (Also did you just call your program "a visual studio"..?)

Comment: yup, sorry my mistake not including it. Yup my IDE is visual studio